# adding toolbarItem to GtkToolbar to specific position on toolbar crashes

Tags: gtk, toolbar

i'm using void gtk_toolbar_insert (GtkToolbar *toolbar, GtkToolItem *item, gint pos);

If i pass -1 or 0 for pos, it works fine.   But if I try any other position, i get assertion failed.  gtktoolbar.c line 2244 logical==0.

i'm basically followed this code:  except for the position.

#include

int main( int argc, char *argv[])
   {

```
 GtkWidget *window;
 GtkWidget *vbox;

 GtkWidget *toolbar;
 GtkToolItem *new;
 GtkToolItem *open;
 GtkToolItem *save;
 GtkToolItem *sep;
 GtkToolItem *exit;


 gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

 window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
 gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);
 gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 250, 200);
 gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "toolbar");

 vbox = gtk_vbox_new(FALSE, 0);
 gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), vbox);


 toolbar = gtk_toolbar_new();
 gtk_toolbar_set_style(GTK_TOOLBAR(toolbar), GTK_TOOLBAR_ICONS);

 gtk_container_set_border_width(GTK_CONTAINER(toolbar), 2);

 new = gtk_tool_button_new_from_stock(GTK_STOCK_NEW);
 gtk_toolbar_insert(GTK_TOOLBAR(toolbar), new, -1);

 open = gtk_tool_button_new_from_stock(GTK_STOCK_OPEN);
 gtk_toolbar_insert(GTK_TOOLBAR(toolbar), open, -1);

 save = gtk_tool_button_new_from_stock(GTK_STOCK_SAVE);
 gtk_toolbar_insert(GTK_TOOLBAR(toolbar), save, -1);

 sep = gtk_separator_tool_item_new();
 gtk_toolbar_insert(GTK_TOOLBAR(toolbar), sep, -1); 

 exit = gtk_tool_button_new_from_stock(GTK_STOCK_QUIT);
 gtk_toolbar_insert(GTK_TOOLBAR(toolbar), exit, -1);

 gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vbox), toolbar, FALSE, FALSE, 5);

 g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(exit), "clicked", 
       G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

 g_signal_connect_swapped(G_OBJECT(window), "destroy",
    G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

 gtk_widget_show_all(window);

 gtk_main();

 return 0;
```

}

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that positions start counting at 0. If you add the items at positions 0, 1, 2, 3, and 4, everything works fine.

PS. If you indent your code by 4 spaces, then Stack Overflow will format it properly and it'll be easier to read and copy.

Comment: So add items in order.  I can't add at 0, then at 10, then at 5.

It must be 0,then 1, then 2,....etc
I will try this